# Is there a way to use several JComboBox in one JPanel

Tags: java, swing

For my UI I have the user make three choices from three drop down boxes. I haven't been able to figure out if there is a way to have all three in one `JPanel`.  So far I just have three different `JPanels`.
How would I add all three drop boxes to one `JPanel`?

Here is my code

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(new JLabel("Please select a country:"));
DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
model.addElement("Great Britian");
model.addElement("United States");
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(model);
panel.add(comboBox);

JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, "Country", 
   JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, 
   JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
panel1.add(new JLabel("Please select a restaurant category"));
DefaultComboBoxModel model1 = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
model1.addElement("Diner");
model1.addElement("Evening Only");
model1.addElement("All day");
JComboBox comboBox1 = new JComboBox(model1);
panel1.add(comboBox1);

JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel1, 
   "Restaurant", 
   JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, 
   JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: Just add components to your main `JPanel`

Comment: -1, Where in your code did you try adding 3 combo boxes to a single panel? And what problems did you have when you tried to do this? Post your `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Smit, thanks.  I was playing around with it for a while and I couldn't find the right combo.

Comment: @Aaron I just posted a working code. It looks like you already got the answer. Good Luck..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add as many components as you want to a `JPanel`

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

panel.add(cbox1);
panel.add(cbox2);
panel.add(cbox3);
```

Why are you trying to put everything ingo a `JOPtionPane`? You should build your own GUI with a `JFrame`

```
public class BoxFrame extends JFrame {
    private JComboBox jcbox1 = new JComboBox(model1);
    private JComboBox jcbox2 = new JComboBox(model2);
    private JComboBox jcbox3 = new JComboBox(model3);
    private JLabel jlb1 = newJLabel("Question1");
    private JLabel jlb2 = newJLabel("Question2");
    private JLabel jlb3 = newJLabel("Question3");
    private JButton jbtSubmit = newJButton("Submit");

    public BoxFrame(){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6, 1));
        panel.add(jlb1);
        panel.add(jcbox1);
        panel.add(jlb2);
        panel.add(jcbox2);
        panel.add(jlb3);
        panel.add(jcbox3);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout(5,5))
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(jbtSubmit,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        jbtSumbit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                String cb1 = jcbox1.getItemSelected();
                String cb2 = jcbox2.getItemSelected();
                String cb3 = jcbox13.getItemSelected();

                // do something with Strings
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        BoxFrame frame = new BoxFrame();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setTitle("ComboBoxes);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationReltaiveTo(null);
        frame.setVisible();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Forgive for some dirty code. As its Friday

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jComboBox2 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jComboBox3 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Combo1");

        jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));

        jLabel2.setText("Combo2");

        jComboBox2.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));

        jLabel3.setText("Combo3");

        jComboBox3.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));

        jPanel1.add(jLabel1);
        jPanel1.add(jComboBox1);
        jPanel1.add(jLabel2);
        jPanel1.add(jComboBox2);
        jPanel1.add(jLabel3);
        jPanel1.add(jComboBox3);

        add(jPanel1);

        pack();
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox2;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;

}
```